# Remove the ability to hold down a keyboard key

Tags: javascript

I have a small page. Circles appear here, when you click on them they disappear.

I added here the possibility that in addition to clicking on the LMB, you can also click on a keyboard key, in my case it is "A".

But I noticed the problem that if you hold down the "A" button, then drive in circles, then the need for clicks disappears, and this is the main goal.

Can I somehow disable the ability to hold this button so that only clicking on it works?

I tried pasting this code, but all animations stopped working for me.

```
var down = false;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function () {
    if(down) return;
    down = true;

    // your magic code here
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    down = false;
}, false);
```

Get error:

> "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: mouseOverHandler is not defined"

```js
//create circle

var clickEl = document.getElementById("clicks");

var spawnRadius = document.getElementById("spawnRadius");
var spawnArea = spawnRadius.getBoundingClientRect();
const circleSize = 95; // Including borders

function createDiv(id, color) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class', id);
    if (color === undefined) {
        let colors = ['#ebc6df', '#ebc6c9', '#e1c6eb', '#c6c9eb', '#c6e8eb', '#e373fb', '#f787e6', '#cb87f7', '#87a9f7', '#87f7ee'];
        randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        div.style.borderColor = randomColor;
    }
    else {
        div.style.borderColor = color;
    }
    
    // Randomly position circle within spawn area
    div.style.top = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * (spawnArea.height - circleSize))}px`;
    div.style.left = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * (spawnArea.width - circleSize))}px`;
    div.classList.add("circle", "animation");

    // Add click handler
    let clicked = false;
    div.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverHandler );
    div.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOutHandler );
    div.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        if (clicked) { return; } // Only allow one click per circle
        clicked = true;
        
        div.style.animation = 'Animation 200ms linear forwards';
        setTimeout(() => { spawnRadius.removeChild(div); }, 220);
    });
    
    spawnRadius.appendChild(div);
}

let i = 0;

const rate = 1000;

setInterval(() => {
    i += 1;
    createDiv(`circle${i}`);
}, rate);

    let focusedEl = null;
    const keyDownHandler = (evt) => { 
      if(evt.keyCode === 65 && focusedEl) focusedEl.click(); 
    }
  const mouseOutHandler = (evt) => focusedEl = null;
  const mouseOverHandler = (evt) => focusedEl = evt.currentTarget;

  document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler );
  window.focus();
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #0f0f0f;
}

.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
}

#spawnRadius {
    top: 55%;
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    left: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #0f0f0f;
    border: 2px solid #ebc6df;
}

@keyframes Animation {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(.8);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="spawnRadius"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you should use different divs

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, you want the `A` button logic completely removed?

Comment: You should honestly use a canvas for this, not adding divs in HTML, so you don't crash units with low memory by constantly adding new elements. Also, it will be easier if you held all elements, and their positions, in memory and just displayed it on a 2dcanvas, so you can track mouse clicks easier.

Comment: @RickardElimää Nothing wrong with a few divs, especially if they get removed anyway.

Comment: @Bergi So what if someone is leaving the game open for a while? Sure, a value of max number of circles would be enough too, but the original code never removes the event listener so it leaks memory.

Comment: They are trying to recreate OSU. The core gameplay is around clicking the circles in the correct order rhythmically. The problem is that when you hold the A key there is no longer skill required in clicking the circles; only holding A and moving your mouse over the circles. They want to disable this to maintain the same behaviour as clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [`repeat` property of the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat), which

> … is `true` if the given key is being held down such that it is automatically repeating.

(but notice the [compatibility notes on *auto-repeat handling*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#auto-repeat_handling))

```js
const keyDownHandler = (evt) => {
    if (!evt.repeat && evt.keyCode === 65) {
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^
        focusedEl?.click();
    }
}

//create circle

var clickEl = document.getElementById("clicks");

var spawnRadius = document.getElementById("spawnRadius");
var spawnArea = spawnRadius.getBoundingClientRect();
const circleSize = 95; // Including borders

function createDiv(id, color) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class', id);
    if (color === undefined) {
        let colors = ['#ebc6df', '#ebc6c9', '#e1c6eb', '#c6c9eb', '#c6e8eb', '#e373fb', '#f787e6', '#cb87f7', '#87a9f7', '#87f7ee'];
        randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        div.style.borderColor = randomColor;
    }
    else {
        div.style.borderColor = color;
    }
    
    // Randomly position circle within spawn area
    div.style.top = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * (spawnArea.height - circleSize))}px`;
    div.style.left = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * (spawnArea.width - circleSize))}px`;
    div.classList.add("circle", "animation");

    // Add click handler
    let clicked = false;
    div.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverHandler );
    div.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOutHandler );
    div.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        if (clicked) { return; } // Only allow one click per circle
        clicked = true;
        
        div.style.animation = 'Animation 200ms linear forwards';
        setTimeout(() => { spawnRadius.removeChild(div); }, 220);
    });
    
    spawnRadius.appendChild(div);
}

let i = 0;

const rate = 1000;

setInterval(() => {
    i += 1;
    createDiv(`circle${i}`);
}, rate);

let focusedEl = null;
const mouseOutHandler = (evt) => focusedEl = null;
const mouseOverHandler = (evt) => focusedEl = evt.currentTarget;

document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler );
window.focus();
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #0f0f0f;
}

.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
}

#spawnRadius {
    top: 55%;
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    left: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #0f0f0f;
    border: 2px solid #ebc6df;
}

@keyframes Animation {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(.8);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="spawnRadius"></div>

</body>
</html>
```